# How To Compute $\int_{-\frac12}^3 \frac{\frac1{x+1}\ln (x+2)}{\ln(x+3)+\ln(x+2)-\ln(x+1)}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate the following integral
$$\int_{-\frac12}^3 \frac{\frac1{x+1}\ln (x+2)}{\ln(x+3)+\ln(x+2)-\ln(x+1)}dx$$

The answer in a closed form seems to be $\frac32 \ln2$.

Comment: $dx$ is missing and $$\ln(x+2)^{1/(x+2)}=\frac{1}{x+2}\ln(x+2)$$

Comment: Sorry I fixed it. BTW, it's $\ln(x+2)^\frac1{x+1}$, not $\ln(x+2)^\frac1{x+2}$.

Comment: Is it $\bigl(\ln(x+2)\bigr)^{1/(x+1)}$ or $\ln\bigl((x+2)^{1/(x+1)}\bigr)$?

Comment: @mickep It's the latter. I realized it was not clear. I took it out to the front for clarity as Dr. Sonnhard suggested.

Comment: here is an "evaluation": $1.03972...$ :-)

Comment: @Math-fun right, I know that the answer in a closed form is $\frac32\ln2$.

Comment: What? Is there a closed form for this integral? Post it right now, what are you waiting for?

Comment: @Ataulfo I just did.

Comment: Is it not rather $\approx \frac32\ln 2$?

Comment: Do you think that the integrand has a primitive? There may exist some other tricks to compute a **definite** integral without computing primitives! :) Do you want the primitive or just a way to compute the definite integral? :)

Comment: @H.R. I don't imagine that the integrand has a primitive. I am okay with a trick that just gives the number. It sounds like you have an idea, right?

Comment: I will let you know if I got something! :) Working on that! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is another example of an integral which is easily solved by the substitution $x \mapsto \frac{1-x}{1+x}$.

This substitution transforms the integral into $$I=\int_{-\frac12}^3 \dfrac{\frac1{1+x} \ln(\frac{3+x}{1+x})}{\ln(x+3)+\ln(x+2)-\ln(x+1)}dx.$$

Taking the average of these two representations yields $$I=\frac12 \int_{-\frac12}^3 \frac1{1+x} dx=\frac32 \ln2.$$

Comment: How do you know to take such a substitution? It seems very unnatural to me.

Comment: @Trogdor The answer is that I got lucky. I always employ this substitution when I'm helpless, and these limits of integration and integrand behaved particularly nice.